# Is this C++11 seqlock implementation correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, locking, lock-free, atomic

My code: https://ideone.com/DZeIZv

```cpp
#include <atomic>

template <class T> class Seqlock {
    std::atomic<int> seq_;
    T val_;

public:
    Seqlock(T value = T())
        : val_(value) {
    }

    // concurrent calls are NOT allowed
    void store(T value) {
        const int seq0 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        seq_.store(seq0 + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

        val_ = value;
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

        seq_.store(seq0 + 2, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    // concurrent calls are allowed
    T load() const {
        for (;;) {
            const int seq0 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if (seq0 & 1) {
                // cpu_relax()
                continue;
            }

            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

            T ret = val_;
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

            const int seq1 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if (seq0 == seq1) {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Is this [seqlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock) implementation correct across all architectures, at least when T is an integral type? Can it be improved?

References I was following:

- https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/seqlock.h
- https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-68.pdf
- https://github.com/rigtorp/Seqlock/

Answer (score 1):

My guideline on memory orders is "Just say no"; I guarantee that if you're using them, you're using them wrong. :)  So I won't attempt to find the exact bug, I'll just assume they all say `seq_cst`. The only thing I'll say about your memory orders is, when you write

```
    seq_.store(seq0 + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
```

can you explain how that's different from

```
    seq_.store(seq0 + 1, std::memory_order_release);
```

?

---

```
Seqlock(T value = T())
```

This constructor should be `explicit`; otherwise you're accidentally permitting

```
Seqlock<int> s = 42;
```

and in fact because of C++17 CTAD you're also permitting

```
Seqlock s = 42;
```

Rule of thumb: make all constructors `explicit` except for those you want the compiler to be able to call implicitly (i.e., copy and move constructors).

---

In `T load() const`, you load `seq1` at the bottom of the loop, and then go around again and immediately load `seq0` from the same location. You could just have set `seq0 = seq1`; i.e.

```
T load() const {
    int seq1 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (true) {
        int seq0 = seq1;
        if (seq0 & 1) {
            // cpu_relax();
        } else {
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            T ret = val_;
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            seq1 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if (seq0 == seq1) {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "Just say no" to barriers is a good approach, but sometimes we can't. In may case, I need to implement an alternative to 64-bit atomics on 32-bit platforms, and using seqlocks is a commonly used solution for this.

Comment: atomic_thread_fence() is different from passing MO to store() in the scope to which the MO applies: in the first case it applies to all stores and loads of all variables, and in the second case it's applied only to specific variable. This is what the spec says, but unfortunately I don't know the exact difference it the instructions produced by compiler.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't "just say no" to barriers (inter-thread synchronization) in general; just to using _memory orders_ to get there. Reasoning about `seq_cst` atomics is difficult but possible. It's when you start throwing in orders like `acquire` and `release` that it gets inhumanly confusing.

Comment: Re the difference between "applies to all stores and loads of all variables" and "applied only to specific variable" — yeah, that's what I meant. Can you explain the difference between these two in this situation? It seems like the only non-atomic variable involved is  `val_`, which is overwritten right after the fence. Hm, since you don't want the hardware to hoist the store to `val_` _before_ the increment of `seq_`, it feels like maybe you want an `acquire` there, not a `release`. ...This is the confusing part that I recommend saying "no" to. Just `seq_cst`! It's the default for a reason.

Comment: `FWIW, I didn't "just say no" to barriers (inter-thread synchronization) in general; just to using memory orders to get there.` Thanks, this is indeed a good advice which I will follow in higher level code. However, using 2 or 3 full fences in such a low-level thing as seqlock (i.e. small in one hand and widely used on the other hand) clearly would be an overkill.

Comment: `Can you explain the difference between these two in this situation?` According to spec, specifying MO for seq would prevent reordering for that specific variable, but is not guaranteed to prevent reordering with other stores/loads. The difference is actually real (though I don't fully understand details), for example see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65697 (a long read...). In this particular case, we need to ensure that the last store to `seq_` wont be executed before store to `val_` is complete. Thus release barrier after store to val_ and before last store to seq_.

Comment: In my understanding, just using, for example, `seq_.store(seq0 + 2, std::memory_order_release)` here will say "don't reorder this store with proceeding stores/loads to seq", but we need "don't reorder this store with ANY proceeding stores/loads". Though my understanding may be incorrect. I'm quite new to this topic. Also, I guess that on some architectures these two will be equivalent. But not on all. E.g. on AArch64, if I understand correctly, just `STLR` is weaker than `DMB ISH` - https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html

Comment: BTW, in my project I decided to provide sequential consistency in Seqlock, by converting *one* of the barriers in store and one in load to seq-cst. This way the code that builds things on top of seqlocks and other primitives becomes simpler, as you suggested.